# sql transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, unpivot

suppose I have the following table:

```
+---------+------+-------------+-----+-------+--------+
| invoice | item | description | qty | price | amount |
+---------+------+-------------+-----+-------+--------+
|    1234 | L    | labour      |   1 |    50 |     50 |
|    1234 | P    | parts       |   2 |   100 |    200 |
|    9865 | L    | labour      |   1 |    25 |     25 |
|    9865 | P    | parts       |   1 |    25 |     25 |
|    5555 | P    | parts       |   2 |   100 |    200 |
+---------+------+-------------+-----+-------+--------+
```

I would like a select query that will transpose the 2 rows to columns for each unique invoice number such that each invoice number has only one row.

so for the above example I would expect the following:

```
+---------+-------+--------------+------+--------+---------+-------+--------------+------+--------+---------+
| invoice | item1 | description1 | qty1 | price1 | amount1 | item2 | description2 | qty2 | price2 | amount2 |
+---------+-------+--------------+------+--------+---------+-------+--------------+------+--------+---------+
|    1234 | L     | labour       |    1 |     50 |      50 | P     | parts        | 2    | 100    | 200     |
|    9865 | L     | labour       |    1 |     25 |      25 | P     | parts        | 1    | 25     | 25      |
|    5555 | P     | parts        |    2 |    100 |     200 | NULL  | NULL         | NULL | NULL   | NULL    |
+---------+-------+--------------+------+--------+---------+-------+--------------+------+--------+---------+
```

Note I'm looking for a static/predefined number of columns, not dynamic based on line items.

Comment: You want a [pivot query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a limited number of values that you want to convert into columns, then you can easily do this using `row_number()` with a CASE expression and an aggregate function:

```
select invoice,
  max(case when seq = 1 then item end) item1,
  max(case when seq = 1 then description end) description1,
  max(case when seq = 1 then qty end) qty1,
  max(case when seq = 1 then price end) price1,
  max(case when seq = 1 then amount end) amount1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then item end) item2,
  max(case when seq = 2 then description end) description2,
  max(case when seq = 2 then qty end) qty2,
  max(case when seq = 2 then price end) price2,
  max(case when seq = 2 then amount end) amount2
from 
(
  select invoice, item, description, qty, price, amount,
    row_number() over(partition by invoice order by invoice) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by invoice;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6df31/5).

But if you want to use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the result, then you will need to look at unpivoting the multiple columns (`item`, `description`, `qty`, `price` and `amount`) first, then apply the pivot function.  The code using PIVOT will be similar to:

```
;with cte as
(
  select invoice, item, description, qty, price, amount,
    row_number() over(partition by invoice order by invoice) seq
  from yourtable
)
select invoice,
  item1, description1, qty1, price1, amount1,
  item2, description2, qty2, price2, amount2
from
(
  select invoice, 
    col = col+cast(seq as varchar(10)), 
    value
  from cte
  cross apply
  (
    select 'item', item union all
    select 'description', description union all
    select 'qty', cast(qty as varchar(50)) union all
    select 'price', cast(price as varchar(50)) union all
    select 'amount', cast(amount as varchar(50))
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (item1, description1, qty1, price1, amount1,
              item2, description2, qty2, price2, amount2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6df31/6). Both will give a result:

```
| INVOICE | ITEM1 | DESCRIPTION1 | QTY1 | PRICE1 | AMOUNT1 |  ITEM2 | DESCRIPTION2 |   QTY2 | PRICE2 | AMOUNT2 |
|    1234 |     L |       labour |    1 |     50 |      50 |      P |        parts |      2 |    100 |     200 |
|    5555 |     P |        parts |    2 |    100 |     200 | (null) |       (null) | (null) | (null) |  (null) |
|    9865 |     L |       labour |    1 |     25 |      25 |      P |        parts |      1 |     25 |      25 |
```